# how to add footer template dynamically in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have created a gridview dynamically. There is template fields described in designing portion. All the columns were created thru code behind as follows. Its works fine. Here I can listed the pages for each rows. But I dont know how to implement the sum of pages in the footer template thru code behind.

```
TemplateField Pages = new TemplateField();
Pages.HeaderText = "Pages";
Pages.ItemTemplate = new GridViewTemplate_Pages();
gv1.Columns.Add(Pages);


    public class GridViewTemplate_Pages : ITemplate
    {

        void ITemplate.InstantiateIn(Control container)
        {
            Label PagesLabel = new Label();
            PagesLabel.DataBinding += new EventHandler(this.PagesLabel_DataBinding);
            container.Controls.Add(PagesLabel);
        }

        void PagesLabel_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label lbl1 = (Label)sender;
            GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)lbl1.NamingContainer;
            lbl1.Text = DataBinder.Eval(row.DataItem, "PagesReceived").ToString();
        }
    }
```

Given ShowFooter="True" in aspx page and RowDataBound written separately. The following code works fine if I given footer template in aspx page but do not know how to get the result in programmatically. Please advice.

```
    protected void gv1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            int RowTotalPages = Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "PagesReceived"));
            TotalPages = TotalPages + RowTotalPages;
        }
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
        {
            Label m = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("gv1TotalPages");
            m.Text = TotalPages.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Its a silly thing. I made it complex. I need the sum of pages in the footer row, then why should I think and confuse about GridViewTemplate and Itemplate class. Simply I added the Total pages in the session and recollect it in the DataControlRowType.Footer. Here is the code:

Comment: protected void gv1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                int RowTotalPages = Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "PagesReceived"));
                TotalPages = TotalPages + RowTotalPages;
                 Session.Add("TotalPages", TotalPages.ToString());
             }
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
            {
                e.Row.Cells[5].Text = Session["TotalPages"].ToString();
             }
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a silly thing. I made it complex. I need the sum of pages in the footer row, then why should I think and confuse about GridViewTemplate and Itemplate class. Simply I added the Total pages in the session and recollect it in the DataControlRowType.Footer. Here is the code:

```
    protected void gv1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            int RowTotalPages = Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "PagesReceived"));
            int RowTotalCharges = Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "ChargesReceived"));
            TotalPages = TotalPages + RowTotalPages;
            TotalCharges = TotalCharges + RowTotalCharges;
            Session.Add("TotalPages", TotalPages.ToString());
            Session.Add("TotalCharges", TotalCharges.ToString());
        }
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[4].Text = "Batches Count: " + gv1.Rows.Count.ToString();
            e.Row.Cells[5].Text = Session["TotalPages"].ToString();
            e.Row.Cells[6].Text = Session["TotalCharges"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create the footer to a gridview like this.

//Code

```
GridView gv = new GridView();
gv.RowCreated += delegate(object dsender, GridViewRowEventArgs ge)
{
    if (ge.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
        ge.Row.Cells[0].Text = "Something";
};
gv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
gv.ShowFooter = true;
BoundField bf = new BoundField();
bf.HeaderText = "col 1";
bf.DataField = "Length";
gv.Columns.Add(bf);
gv.DataSource = new string[] { "One", "Two", "Three" };
gv.DataBind();
Form.Controls.Add(gv);
```

This is for the dynamically created gridview and a footer. You can change accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. But above code will place the word "Something" in the footer. I want to add the sum of pages in the dynamically created "Pages" template field. So please let me know how to code inside the Itemplate class.

Comment: What do u mean by pages and adding the sum of that?